# Django two projects on two separate servers with one database

Tags: django, rest

I have a Django application that does quite expensive computation and then populates a database. I would like to serve the results using the Django Rest Framework. I would like to keep the application and the API on separate server instances so that I can ensure that the outgoing API is never deprived of resources. This means that both projects will be using the same tables in a shared database. Is there a way to achieve this without at least one of the projects having to perform raw SQL queries? I.e. Can I share both the database and the models (with querysets etc) between two projects on separate servers? Or is that not possible?

Note: I've looked at a lot of similar questions but the answers were not useful.

Thanks!

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38753431

Comment: Hey thanks. Forgot about this was more than a year ago. I realised quite soon that I didn't need two separate the application and the api. I could just deploy the same thing twice. The full program with the api and the application is now in one django project deployed on multiple servers.

Comment: Thanks @neil, good to know your issue was solved.