# How to use multiple database in Django

Tags: django

I have to use two databases, one is a third party db(MySql) for which I only have read access. Another db is my Django application's db(Postgres).

I need to access the third party's sql db , to run some calculations and use my Django applications db(Postgres) to store those calculated values.

I am very new to Django, I understand the concept of Models , but my knowledge is very limited to adding users logging them in etc. Can anybody point me in the right direction or let me know about some best practices to be followed in order to achieve this ?

To stream line my question, after adding both db details in settings.py what will happen when I run migrate command ? Especially the third party db ?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753431/django-and-read-only-database-connections) helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The `migrate` management command operates on one database at a time. By default, it operates on the default database. Check more info in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases)