# How to access a legacy database without creating a new table in it in Django

Tags: django, database, migration, legacy-database

I was given access to a database to use on one of my Django projects. I set everything up and went to migrate the new models and I got an error.

"Unable to create the django_migrations table ((1142, "CREATE command denied
to user 'MyDatabaseName' for table 'django_migrations'"))"

After looking into it, I see its because Django is trying to create a new table in that database.
I don't have write access and I do not want it because I am pretty new at this and do not want to mess anything up. I am also not sure the owner would give it to me.
Is there a way to get to use the legacy database without having to create a new table in it?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43553063/1246764

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django and read-only database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753431/django-and-read-only-database-connections)